# Can multiple button use same ModalPopupExtender window?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have a list of addresses on my page, each has a edit button. When click edit, I want to use the same ModalPopupExtender. Is this possible?

Thanks. I am using asp .net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you fetching the list from database? If yes, use a data control like gridview & use a template field for edit button. [Add Edit Gridview using modal popup](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Edit-Update-Records-in-GridView-using-Modal-Popup-in-ASP.Net.aspx)